# How to make a prefixed string class?

Tags: c#, string

I need a class of `string` objects to handle *hexadecimal strings*. It should behave *exactly* as `string`, but very `string` should be *lowercase* and *prefixed* with `"0x"`.

Something like this

```
class PString :String
{
      // some magic here
}

PString s0 = "aaaAa";

s0.ToString();  //should be "0xaaaaa";
```

Comment: What if I put `PString s0 = "bla-bla-bla (not hex at all)!";`? Shall the return be `"0xbla-bla-bla (not hex at all)!"`

Comment: not sure how useful this whole question is... normally such values should be stored as _integers_ in a program, not as _strings_.

Comment: PString s0 = "bla-bla-bla (not hex at all)!" should throw.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than build a custom class for this, you could simply store your values as integers. Then, when you need to display them as hex, use `.toString()` [standard numeric formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

```
int myInt = 100;
string myHexString = myInt .ToString("X");
```

Comment: My strings are very-very long.

Comment: So, may be I should use System.Numerics.Biginteger or byte arrays

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using implicit casts:

```
public class PString
{
    private string data;
    public static implicit operator string(PString value) => value.ToString();
    public static implicit operator PString(string value) => new PString(value);

    public PString(string value) => data = value;
    public override string ToString() => $"0x{data.ToLower()}";
}
```

See it in action [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SdhUcl).
If it should be limited to or checked for only valid character this can be combined with the solution from @DimitryBychenko like:

```
public class PString
{
    private string data;
    public static implicit operator string(PString str) => str.ToString();
    public static implicit operator PString(string str) => new PString(str);

    public PString(string value)
    {
        if (value?.Any(c => !(c >= '0' && c <= '9' || 
                      c >= 'a' && c <= 'f' || 
                      c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')) == true)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect value format", "value")
        }
        data = value;  
    }
    public override string ToString()
        => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) ? String.Empty : $"0x{data.ToLower()}";
}
```

Comment: need to add restriction to non hexademical char values.

Comment: @aleha Yes, but that was not the question of the OP. If such a requirement is added I will also add it, but maybe the OP can solve that part on his own ;-)...

Comment: I thought that the phrase **to handle hexademical strings** is self-requirement...

Comment: @aleha I followed the given example. The phrase could also be understood as if the strings are always hexadecimal and no additional check is needed (e.g. it is checked elsewhere). But I'll add an example for the constraint based on Dimitry's solution...

Comment: How about PString to behave as System.String? I need to have length, Substring, StartsWith, Contains, PadWith, operator+, ability to have Int.Parse() on PString. So PString should be String, but I don;t want to implement all the above methods in manual.

Comment: @XeenychXeenych Two possibilities: 1) cast it back and forth to string or 2) implement the desired methods in the `PString` class. As `System.String` is sealed you can not have it "exactly" the same way as this would require inheritance. You can just mimic the behavior as good as possible...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a (extension) *method* for the existing `String` class, not a custom *class*: if

> It should behave **exactly** as `string`

then the class is `string`

```
 public static partial class StringExtensions {
   public static string ToStringHex(this string value) {
     if (null == value)
       return null; // Or throw ArgumentNullException

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
       return "";   // Or throw ArgumentException

     // Let's be nice and let 0x... strings
     if (value.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       value = value.Substring(2);

     if (value.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' || 
                        c >= 'a' && c <= 'f' || 
                        c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')) 
       return $"0x{value.ToLowerInvariant()}";

     throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect value format", "value"); 
   }
 }
```

...

```
 String s0 = "aaaAa"; 

 String result = s0.ToStringHex();
```

Comment: Just like my initial suggestion, only better :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Alas, System.String is sealed, so you can't inherit it.
You can, however, add an extension method to it:

```
public static string AddHexPrefix(this string str)
{
    return "0x" + str;
}
```

Or create a class that will hold a string inside, and add an implicit operator to it:

```
public class HexString 
{
    private string _string;

    public HexString(string str)
    {
        _string = str;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "0x" + _string;
    }

    public static implicit operator HexString(string str)
    {
        return new HexString(str);
    }
}
```

Of course, this does not ensure in any way that the string you get is in fact a hexa-decimal value - currently, nothing is stopping you from doing something like this:

```
HexString s = "Zohar";
```

To do that, you should check that the string you get in your constructor contains only 0-9 and a-f, and throw an exception if not.
so your class should probably look like this:

```
private static Regex validator = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"); // no need to create it over and over again in the constructor

public HexString(string str)
{
    if(!validator.IsMatch(str))
        throw new FormatException("The string was not recognized as a valid hexa-decimal value");
    _string = str;
}
```

That being said, I have to agree with Soviut - You should probably just use an int to store the value and convert it to hex using `ToString("x")`.

Answer (score 1):

In your class write:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return "0x" + s0.ToLower();
}
```

String class is sealed and you can't inherit it. In this case should be written own class with method who returns value like this. Like `=> "0x" + s0.value.ToLower()`

Comment: System.String is sealed. You can't inherit a sealed class.

Comment: Hmm.. In this case should be written own class with method who returns value like this..